# bash_profile error on line 18?

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems

I'm having trouble setting up my bash profile, 
I created it via using terminal, and the bash_profile is an empty document currently.

Now when I type in source ~/.bash_profile into terminal I am given the following response?

```
jakes-mbp:~ Jake$ source ~/.bash_profile
bash: eval: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

please help?

Comment: Is `~/.bash_profile` *really* empty? When I `source` an empty file, I don’t an error. It looks to me that the file has an `eval` in it, which would be consistent with how `rbenv` operates.

Comment: I completely deleted the bash_profile and started again and everything has continued working smoothly now, not sure what was happening.